# svn: Can't open file '.svn/lock': Permission denied on MAc

Tags: svn, macos

I can't make this go away and I've tried everything. I don't really care how horrible and hacky the answer is, I just want it to go away. Can anyone help? Thanks.

EDIT:

I'm trying to basic commands, i.e.

```
cd MyDirectory/
svn update
```

Comment: Fantastic. This helped me today.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You might not have write permission on the directory

```
sudo chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) MyDirectory
chmod -R u+w MyDirectory
```

Comment: That's beautiful. Absolutely beautiful. Thanks a lot. I'll mark it as the correct answer in 7 minutes. Cheers.